# Not able to connect to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

While connecting to the DB via SQL Developer, I'm facing following error:
    ***Io Exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection***

I tried to find out the issue and end up seeing that the OracleXETNsListener service is not started.
I tried to start it but getting error as : ***The OracleXETNSListener service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs***

also tried it through command prompt as follows:

```
C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 16-JUN-2014 15:00
:43

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Message 1053 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSTNS-125
57: Message 12557 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
 TNS-12560: Message 12560 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facili
ty=TNS
  TNS-00527: Message 527 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facilit
y=TNS
```

Comment: Do you have ORACLE_HOME set? That might explain the 'message not found' errors from the command line. For the service you need to find the log file and see why that shut down. Is this a new or recent installation? Is the listener configured for localhost or an external IP address, and does the PC have a static IP or is using DHCP?

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thanx for the reply. This is not new installation. The liostener is configured for localhost. Also my system does have static ip address. Where i can find this log file for listener?

Comment: @AlexPoole: i also set the oracle_home but still giving me same msg for 'lsnrctl status' command

Answer (score 4):

That happened to me when I set the variables `ORACLE_HOME` & `ORACLE_SID`, restarted and that error appeared.

Possible Solution: I deleted variables `ORACLE_HOME` & `ORACLE_SID`, restarted my computer and everything went ok.